# Pandas: Selecting last "N" columns

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I have a `df` in which I am trying to select the last half of the columns (selection by column label is not an option due to variable number of columns).

```
length = len(rec_df.columns)
print(length)
selection = rec_df.columns[-length/2:]
print(selection)
```

Quite clearly, when I print `length`, I get `6`, but I get an error when using the `length` variable to index.

However, if I simply change `-length/2:` -> `-3:`, it works. How can make this work for variable `length`?

Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slice indices must be an int, try this:

```
length = int(len(rec_df.columns)/2)
print(length)
selection = rec_df.columns[-length:]
print(selection)
```

Comment: Well it doesn't throw an error but it definitely doesn't give me the result I would expect. Right now, `rec_df.columns` = `Index(['AAPL values', 'GOOG values', 'MSFT values', 'AAPL shares',
       'GOOG shares', 'MSFT shares'],
      dtype='object')` and your solution only returns `Index(['MSFT shares'], dtype='object')` (the last column)

Comment: it looks like that works, let me check one more thing

Comment: The previous method should work too, I tried both ways. Not sure why it didn't, that method is a lot cleaner for you to assign an variable and have it change as necessary

Answer (score 0):

Does `df.columns[len(df.columns) - n:]` do what you wish to achieve ? Since you asked for **n** columns.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([range(6), range(6), range(6), range(6), range(6), range(6)], columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'])
df
#   a  b  c  d  e  f
#0  0  1  2  3  4  5
#1  0  1  2  3  4  5
#2  0  1  2  3  4  5
#3  0  1  2  3  4  5
#4  0  1  2  3  4  5
#5  0  1  2  3  4  5

n = 2
df.columns[len(df.columns) - n:]
#Index([u'e', u'f'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: The last "N" columns is logically defined by `len(df.columns)/2`. Substituting this for `n` in your solution still raises error.

Comment: If you want the half, make it so N is half, or do `df.columns[len(df.columns)/2:]`. It works for me. :)

Comment: lol yes but `len(df.columns)` will change depending on other parameters I did not include in the minimal example so supplying an arbitrary value for `n` would only work for one specific case of many

Comment: If you want a better answer, you are welcome to make a better question. :) -- if you do not include what you fully want, we can't decide for you.